# How to read data from Excel and write it to text file line by line?

Tags: python, xlrd

I want to write code to get data from Excel and write it to a text file. Here is the code I have:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\TRB 2014 Data','SPS1 demo data.xlsx'))
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
i = 1

while sh.cell(i,11).value != 0:

   Load = sh.cell(i,11).value
   D1 = sh.cell(i,13).value
   D2 = sh.cell(i,14).value
   D3 = sh.cell(i,15).value
   D4 = sh.cell(i,16).value
   D5 = sh.cell(i,17).value
   D6 = sh.cell(i,18).value
   D7 = sh.cell(i,19).value
   DB1 = str(Load) + "  " + str(D1) + "  " + str(D2) + "  " + str(D3)+ "  " + str(D4)+ "  " + str(D5)+ "  " + str(D6)+ "  " + str(D7)

   file = open("Output.txt", "w")
   file.write(DB1 + '\n')
   file.close
   i = i + 1
```

The problem with this code is the data written to the text file is always displayed at the first row. Therefore, although I have 20 rows of data in excel, the text file only shows the last data in the excel file at the very first row in the text file. I have `'\n'` in `file.write` but, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the `output.txt` file with `append mode`:

```
file = open("Output.txt", "a")
```

Also, you should do this before entering the loop, and it should be closed after that loop.

---

**Update**:

In cases like this one, you could use `with` instead of closing the file handle at the end.

Also including the good suggestion made by [@Josh in his own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17977823/677022), the code could be this:

```
import xlrd
import os.path

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\TRB 2014 Data','SPS1 demo data.xlsx'))
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
i = 1
with open("Output.txt", "a") as my_file:
    while sh.cell(i,11).value != 0:
        Load = sh.cell(i,11).value
        all_d = sh.col_values(i, 13, 19)
        DB1 = Load + " " + (" ".join(all_d))
        my_file.write(DB1 + '\n')
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import xlrd

workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("xxx.xls")
sh=workbook.sheet_by_name("test1")
print sh.nrows
print sh.ncols
n=0
i=0
file=open("xxx.txt","w")
for n in range(sh.nrows):
    for i in range(sh.ncols):
        data =sh.cell_value(n,i)+" "
        print  data,
        file.write(data+" ")
    print 
    file.write("\n")
 this code is working properly for writing into text file
```

Comment: its better to use `sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)` when sheet name is unknown

Answer (score 2):

You are opening and closing your output file for each line in the Excel sheet.

Open the file before the while loop and then then close it when done with the loop.

```
import xlrd
import os.path
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\TRB 2014 Data','SPS1 demo data.xlsx'))
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
i = 1
file = open("Output.txt", "w")
while sh.cell(i,11).value != 0:
   Load = sh.cell(i,11).value
   D1 = sh.cell(i,13).value
   D2 = sh.cell(i,14).value
   D3 = sh.cell(i,15).value
   D4 = sh.cell(i,16).value
   D5 = sh.cell(i,17).value
   D6 = sh.cell(i,18).value
   D7 = sh.cell(i,19).value
   DB1 = str(Load) + "  " + str(D1) + "  " + str(D2) + "  " + str(D3)+ "  " + str(D4)+ "  " + str(D5)+ "  " + str(D6)+ "  " + str(D7)

   file.write(DB1 + '\n')
   i = i + 1
file.close
```

Comment: This should also improve performance, as the file isn't being opened and closed over and over.

Comment: One problem with this is that the there is nothing in the saved text file

Comment: Did you try with `file.close()` as last line?

Comment: I did. Maybe there is a delay between file creation and final saved file. I will double check if the code works or not.

Comment: Use 'with' as suggested in Nicolás' answer

Answer (score 2):

xlrd actually has a nice function for grabbing the values of a bunch of cells all in a column or row. Using that, you can simplify your code a lot (and I'm pretty sure their function is more efficient). That way your code can become:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('D:\TRB 2014 Data','SPS1 demo data.xlsx'))
wb.sheet_names()
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
i = 1
my_file = open("Output.txt", "a")

while sh.cell(i,11).value != 0:
    Load = sh.cell(i,11).value
    all_d = sh.col_values(i, 13, 19)
    DB1 = Load+" "+(" ".join(all_d))
    my_file.write(DB1 + '\n')
    i += 1
file.close
```