# how to read large amount of data from excel sheet and write into text file in Python

Tags: python

I am reading the data from excel but it is not writing to text file. 
I tried the code is shown below:

```
import xlrd
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("Testit.xls")
worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
numrows=worksheet.nrows-1
curr_row=-1
while curr_row < numrows:
    curr_row +=1
    row=worksheet.row(curr_row)
    print row

fp=open("xxx.txt",'w')
data=fp.write()
print data
```

Comment: Maybe you could export your [.xlsx to a .csv file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18533282/2698552)

Comment: No i tried all the possible. Just try if you get let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [How to read data from Excel and write it to text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977584/how-to-read-data-from-excel-and-write-it-to-text-file-line-by-line) , it is a quite similar question.

But, overall, and among others, you are not writing anything in fp, because the "()" are empty. fp should be opened before the while, and on each iteration of this while you should write the row on it. And remember to close the fp.

Something like this:

```
import xlrd
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook("Testit.xls")
worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
numrows=worksheet.nrows-1
curr_row=-1
fp=open("xxx.txt",'w')
while curr_row < numrows:
    curr_row +=1
    row=worksheet.row(curr_row)
    fp.write(str(row))
fp.close()
```

But remember to look at the link, it explains and solves your problem.

Comment: When i tried the code .It show this error as TypeError: expected a character buffer object  I tried the link which u sent but i need whatever excel sheet data is there it should be present in text file as per row and column. Try to give some idea

Comment: I edited the code. It was the fp.write, you need to put a str() inside it.

It works now.

The text will look as, for example, for A and D in different cell: [text:u'A', text:u'D'] Is that what you wanted?

Comment: ya its work thank u Garcia. Actually i have doubt when u r reading the data from excel to text file . the numerical value is showing like float for example: the value in excel is 45 but in text file is showing that 45.0 . this should not be.. pls solve this issue